# PHP Word Count with approximate result to Word Counter

Tags: php, regex

I'm programming a small web app to manage texts with external writers, actually the whole thing is great but I have a small problem. And it's related with the word counter.

The writers will be paid based on the number of words in text, the text contains html tags. But the problem is that there are german characters used(Ä, Ö, Ü, ß)

So at the first position I deleted the tags

```
    $content = strip_tags($content);
```

then I replace new lines and tabs with simple spaces

```
    $replace   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "\t");
    $content = str_replace($replace, ' ', $content);
```

and finally I try to get the number of words

Method 1:

```
    $characterMap = 'ÄÖÜäöüß€';
    $count = str_word_count($content, 0, $characterMap);
```

Method 2:

```
    $to_delete = array('.', ',', ';', "'", '@');
    $content = str_replace($to_delete, '', $content);

    $count = count(preg_split('~[^\p{L}\p{N}\']+~u',$content));
```

but the results are different to others like the ones from Word, or from CKEditor Plugin word_count.

For example for an Example Text

Word and CkEditor Word Count give 987 Words

Method 1: 968 Words

Method 2: 995 Words

The problem bei the second method are just the - separators by the words, but my question is if there is a better method to find the number of words in a text in php?

Comment: If you are paying by the word then it looks like `Method 1` is best :)

Comment: Why use the character array at all? Do they get paid more for using German characters? Have you tried using `str_word_count` with just `$content`? Moreover, you could combine your punctuation and newline replacement statements into one expression.

Comment: of course, php does come with a [word count function built in](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)....

Comment: What word count do you get when you split the text on `\s+` and count the number of elements of the resulting array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could combine your two replace statements into one -- word count will ignore double spaces. Second, I'm unsure what the objective is of your regex, but it looks mighty strange.

You should be able to simply do this:

```
$content = strip_tags($content);
$replace = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "\t", '.', ',', ';', "'", '@');
$content = str_replace($replace, ' ', $content);
$count = str_word_count($content, 0, $characterMap);
```

Comment: That could be used but I replace new lines with single spaces, ". , ;  @" are being removed, the next problem is that str_word_count count less than Word but it's because Word counts - as a Word and PHP not.

Comment: Right, I see that - so first, str_word_count ignores double spaces (it counts all whitespace as a single space), so replacing all of that with `' '` works. Second, if you try this out, the count is most certainly accurate (count words yourself if you like). Word might not be?

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking a look at str_word_count and see if that matches up better than your current solutions.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

An example of usage being

```
$Tag  = 'My Name is Gaurav'; 
$word = str_word_count($Tags);
echo $word;
```

Comment: That's already in the example... `$count = str_word_count($content, 0, $characterMap);`

Comment: Oh haha, my fault. I'm not sure why I did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

This might give a better approximation for method 2:

```
 $string = "He€.llo, ho-w€d9   €   are you? fi€ne ÄÖÜäöüß€, and 'ÄÖÜäöüß€ you?";
 $words = preg_split
     ( '/[^\p{L}\p{N}]*\p{Z}[^\p{L}\p{N}]*/u',
         $string
     );
 print( "count = " . count($words) .  "\n\n" );
 print_r($words);
```